# Meteor CSV Export

Tags: javascript, csv, meteor

I am trying to export data into CSV using following function

```
   function exportHtml(monthNo){
var data = [];
data.push('Person;Salary;Workover');
let query = Meteor.users.find().fetch().map(function(u){
var userFirst = u.profile.name_first;
var userLast = u.profile.name_last;
var currentId = u._id;

try {
var sum = Salaries.findOne({"userId": {$eq: currentId}, "month": {$eq: monthNo}, "year": {$eq: parseFloat(earningFilterYear.get())} } , {sort:{createdAt: -1}}).cost; 
var hours = Salaries.findOne({"userId": {$eq: currentId}, "month": {$eq: monthNo}, "year": {$eq: parseFloat(earningFilterYear.get())} } , {sort:{createdAt: -1}}).over; 
}catch(e){
}

if(!sum)
sum = 0;
data.push('\r\n');
data.push(userFirst+' '+userLast+';'+sum+';'+hours);
});
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('download', "Export_"+monthNo+"_"+earningFilterYear.get()+".csv");
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8;' + data);
link.click(); 
Bert.alert('Data exported successfully', 'success' );

};
```

Expected behavior

```
Person;Salary;Workover
Name1;5;15
Name2;12;125
```

Reality (one line, ignore undefined)

```
,Admin Account;295.5;5,,Sergo Sarkjan;0;undefined,,Anton Lidat;0;undefined,,Aleksei Dmijev;0;undefined
```

It seems that new line isn't added even tho I have the \r\n, I have also tried  without success, in addition for some reason there are these random commas all over the document. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Change `data:text/html` to `data:text/plain` and replace in the same line `data` with `data.join('')`.

It should look like this:

```
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + data.join(''));
```

Comment: If I attempt to use data.join('') my google chrome doesn't even download the file, giving me a network error.

Comment: Ah, that could be because there should be `,` instead of `;` right after `utf-8`. Sorry, my answer had this error too, I'll fix it now.

Comment: Helpful link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: Sadly, same issue, even with semicolon

Comment: Which issue exactly?

Comment: Google Chrome refuses to download it, giving me Failed - Network Error, however without the .join(''); function it works, sadly without the new lines

Comment: Did you replace `;` with `,` like in my answer?

Comment: Yeah, I tried both, they're giving me the same result, if I try without .join then it works. I also tried on multiple browsers, using Meteor 1.4.4